# Proc in validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm going through my new project where proc is used for validation which i didn't understood.
Can anyone please explain me what is happening here? My code goes like this in a model

```
before_validation :strip_whitespace, :if => proc{|datefield|datefield.export_date_format.present?}

def strip_whitespace
  self.export_date_format.strip!
end
```

Why are we using proc here and why can't we check datefield.export_date_format.present? in if condition directly and call :strip_whitespace method?. What exactly proc is doing here?

Answer (score 0):

1.Why don't check format directly in a method? Maybe it's part of design to keep the method and the procedure to call that method or not as two different parameters. And proc here is object, that's why it possible to pass the procedure as parameter because proc is [first class object](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls#More_on_Procs).

2.It's convenient to define procedure right in the place then define the method and then call this method only once. That's what called the anonymous function in other languages.

3.Sometimes it's only way to define the procedure that can be only proc or lambda. For example in [#108 named_scope](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) Ryan Bates had to use lambda:

```
lambda {|*args| {:conditions => ["released_at > ?",(args.first || 2.weeks.ago)]}}
```

Because the expression `2.weeks.ago` should be evaluated at the time when this lambda is calling but not at the time when expression was loaded.